# Rails: update nested attribute having a unique constraint in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models: Interview and Interviewee

Interview to Interviewee is Many to One relationship. I am creating a form for creating a new Interview through which I also accept the nested attributes for Interviewee. There is also a field "email" having unique constraint in Interviewee model.

**If an Interviewee having the specified "email" already exists in the model, then I simply want to link the Interview to it.**

Here are my models:

Interviewee.rb:

```
class Interviewee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :interviews, inverse_of: :interviewee

    def self.find_by_email(email)
        where("email = ?", email)
    end
end
```

Interview.rb:

```
class Interview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :interviewee, inverse_of: :interviews
  has_many :meetings
  has_many :interviewers, through: :meetings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :interviewee
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :interviewers
end
```

Interview Controller:

```
class InterviewsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @interviews = Interview.all
    end

    def new
        @interview = Interview.new(date: Date.current)
        #2.times {@interview.interviewers.build}
        @interview.interviewers.build
        @interview.build_interviewee
    end

    def create
        render plain: interview_params["interviewee_attributes"]["email"].inspect
        @interview = Interview.new(interview_params)
        logger.debug "#{@interview.interviewee.email}"

        # Check if the interviewee already exists
        interviewee = Interviewee.find_by(email:@interview.interviewee.email)

        if interviewee.present?
            logger.debug "Interviewee exists, linking to it"
            @interview.interviewee.id = interviewee.id
        else
            logger.debug "Interviewee does not exist"
        end



        # Check if the interviewers already exists

        # If they, exist, display alert message on frontend
        #begin
        @interview.save
           #redirect_to interviews_url
        # rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => ex
        #     logger.error "#{ex}"
        #     flash[:error] = "#{ex}"
        #     redirect_to new_interview_url
        # end
    end

    private
        def interview_params
            params.require(:interview).permit(
                :title, :date, :start_time, :end_time,
                interviewee_attributes: [:id, :email],
                interviewers_attributes: [:id, :email]
            )
        end
end
```

When I try to save an Interviewee whose email is already present in the table, It gives me this error:

**SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: interviewees.id: INSERT INTO "interviewees" ("id", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)**

Shouldn't it just create the Interview model without inserting into the Interviewee model as I am passing it an already existing id as given in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html ?

Regards.